# What should be the approach for user friendly way to automate

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation

I want to implement a **user friendly way for automation**. The scenario is very general for automating a test case which can be applicable for networking domain.

- First part is defining `network diagram` (topology - combination of linux machines, router, switch, gateway, etc devices) where I need ideas for more simpler form which can be used by manual testers also who don't have idea about automation stuff.
- One most common way is `making a separate file for topology` other than main script, which will be with all relevant instances of device variables and connections.
- Then using those variables in main script for establishing telnet/ssh connections, but the limitation is, if the setup/topology changes, one has to manually edit that file with new variables and connections.

I would like to know if there is any other way to resolve this manual effort and `make it fully automated`.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like writen for you: https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/learning_by_doing_writing_your
or you can use standard windows command "tracert" or linux "traceroute". You can run this once a while and update your database/file with new topology.
Also I would suggest using database and not files for data storage.

Comment: The OP is trying to find ways to automate telnet / ssh shell interaction with a router or switch.